# Adding Value to ComboBox from Excel using Winform C#

Tags: c#, windows, excel, winforms, combobox

With Below attached Excel [Used Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P9vg.png)

```
   //Establish a Connection
            string XlxPath = @"C:\Users\BreakIn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test\TestData\Test Data.xlsx";
            string XlxPathCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + XlxPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";
            OleDbCommand MyDataAdp = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbConnection Xlxconn = new OleDbConnection(XlxPathCon);
            MyDataAdp.Connection = Xlxconn;

          //  Accessing Sheets
            Xlxconn.Open();
            DataTable xdt;
            // Get all Sheets in Excel File
            xdt = Xlxconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            Xlxconn.Close();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            String SheetName = xdt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            MyDataAdp.CommandText = "SELECT Test From[" + SheetName + "]";

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyDataAdp);
            da.SelectCommand = MyDataAdp;
            da.Fill(ds);

            Testdes.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow value in xdt.Rows)

            {
                Testdes.DataSource = ds.Tables["SheetName"].Columns["test"];
                Testdes.Items.Add(value["test"]);
            }
           Testdes.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

where "Testdes" is combobox.

How to get the values present in excel in specific Rows for Column "C" into ComboBox.

Comment: Start removing the _Testdes.DataSource = ..._ line

Comment: If you provide additional info, such as: compile error or runtime error it might be easier to provide answer.

Comment: There is no error, it runs through the code without adding any value to Combobox

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are no errors?
It looks like the beginning quotation mark of your extended properties is missing

```
";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";
```

should be:

```
";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";
```

Comment: thanks, i have corrected that now and, the code runs till "DataTable xdt;" and opens the fom contaning the combobox.

Comment: and combobox does not contain any value